# How do I change the view path at runtime

Tags: zend-framework2

In my ZF2 app I want to change the Template directory at runtime.

The default path is set in `module.config.php`:

```
'template_path_stack' => array(
        __DIR__ . '/../view',
 ),
```

I would like to change that to the equivalent of

```
'template_path_stack' => array(
        __DIR__ . '/../view-alternate',
 ),
```

at runtime, so I can dynamically change the theme of the page based on the user preference which is stored in the DB.

Answer (score 0):

Template name resolving is a heavy process. It is better to provide the template name manually.

I recommend you to use 'template_map' instead of 'template_path_stack'. You can create some kind of naming convention to differentiate between the two themes, it can be a prefix that you can manage dynamically.

There is a tool to transform the stack into a template map: https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/bin/templatemap_generator.php

Comment: So you are suggesting to set the template using `setTemplate()` in the controller?

Comment: Or better in onBootstrap() inside of your Module.php. This way you do not repeat code through your controllers.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I ended up with is to use https://github.com/ZendExperts/ZeTheme.

Combined with the option too save the theme in the session I was able to change the theme because it's not *at runtime*. A page reload was necessary.

It's a workaround. Not the answer.